# select unique fields on join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, unique

```
CREATE TABLE Face.Person 
   ("LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "TICKET_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE));

insert into Person(last_name,ticket_number) values('johnson','100');
insert into Person(last_name,ticket_number) values('smith','200');

CREATE TABLE Face.Orders 
   ("REGION" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "STATE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "A_CODE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
    "STORE_NUM" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "TICKET_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    "SEQ" NUMBER(12));

insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) values('100', 'S', 'F1', '111', 'Mia', 1);
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) values('100', 'S', 'F1', '222', 'FLL', 2);
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) values('100', 'S', 'F1', '333', 'PBI', 3);
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) values('100', 'S', 'F1', '444', 'BOC', 4);


SELECT A.LAST_NAME, A.TICKET_NUMBER, B.REGION, B.STATE 
FROM PERSON A
  JOIN Orders B ON A.TICKET_NUMBER 
    = (SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE A.TICKET_NUMBER= B.TICKET_NUMBER 
  AND ROWNUM = 1);
```

Join both tables on ticket Number. Person is a one to many relationship with Orders. Multiple orders exist but just need one Orders record(out of 4) that matches with ticket number from both tables.The reason being is the fields required from the Orders table remain the same for all records with same ticket Number.

Expected result:

```
Johnson 100 S Fl
```

Johnson and 100 from `person` table and S and FL, which remain the same for all records per unique ticket number, are from `Orders` table

Oracle 12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear on what basis you are selecting the records from `Orders`. One option is to simply chose `MIN()` of `region` & `state` with a group by and then join it with `Person`

```
WITH b AS (
     SELECT ticket_number,
            MIN(region) AS region,
            MIN(state) AS state
     FROM orders
     GROUP BY ticket_number
) SELECT a.last_name,
         a.ticket_number,
         b.region,
         b.state
  FROM person a
  JOIN b ON a.ticket_number = b.ticket_number;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=49852e483605427cd4ce9debac73390f)

Comment: Thanks - updated it to use select and add another column in the sub select and checked fields in the sub and outer select for null.

Comment: SELECT a.last_name,
         a.ticket_number,
         b.region,
         b.state,
         b.SEQ1
  FROM person a
  JOIN (SELECT ticket_number, MIN(SEQ) AS SEQ1,
            MIN(region) AS region,
            MIN(state) AS state
     FROM orders WHERE REGION IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY ticket_number
) b ON a.ticket_number = b.ticket_number where a.last_name is not null;

Comment: @javacoder : You're welcome. If it worked for you, consider accepting the answer so that it'll also help  others